# UINavigationBar leftBarButtonItem position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have an iOS project with `UINavigationController`.
When I `pushviewcontroller` with

**animated = YES**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

the top `leftbarbuttonitem` (with image) is well positioned.
But if I set `pushviewcontroller` with

**animated = NO**

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

the top `leftbarbuttonitem` (with image) is not positioned exactly the same place with previous one. Does anyone have any idea?

SAMPLE CODE

```
- (void)addBackButtonWithoutAnimation {
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIImage *closeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back"];
UIBarButtonItem *closeBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:closeImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(closeBackButtonwithoutAnimationDidClick)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = closeBackButton;
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;}
```

Comment: Have you done any customization to the back button? like replaced with image or something?

Comment: Yes, replace with image

Comment: can you paste the code and where you put it?

Comment: Done Edited my post =)

Comment: in the ViewDidLoad you call for `addBackButtonWithoutAnimation` right?

Comment: Nop, i call it in ViewWillAppear

Comment: in the ViewDidLoad is it same? normally what i would do is initialize back buttons in Appdelegate. but your way also should work.

Comment: Yes, it works, but the position is a bit off

Comment: try to put this logic to the ViewDidApper method

Comment: @wes.i I believe you must be using the same image "icon_back" while pushing with and without animation, if not issue could be with image.